# Androids CoordinatorLayout scroll behavior to deeper child views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

Question in a nut shell:

How can i attach a scroll behavior to a RecyclerView which isn't a direct child of CoordinatorLayout?

```
<CoordinatorLayout id="root">
    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar/>
    </AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout id ="fragment_container">
        <RecyclerView id="list" behavior="..."/>
    </FrameLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Why i want this?

I have one activity which holds the toolbar and has a main slot for content like a list of "Foo". The list is encapsulated in a Fragment which contains a FrameLayout with a RecyclerView, empty State TextView and a ProgressView. The problem is that the first row in my RecyclerView is behind the toolbar.

Comment: Here is the start point for you: [Nested scrolling with `CoordinatorLayout` on android](https://lab.getbase.com/nested-scrolling-with-coordinatorlayout-on-android/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try to replace your FrameLayout with NestedScrollView**

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

or make this as parent view of your FrameLayout

It work for me